# When I am using System.out.println(N2) outside the loop, it is printing the value of N2. But not inside loop. why?

Tags: java

this code is not executing, even if I am trying to print anything at the starting of the loop before the logic......

```
for(int j=0; j<N2; j++){

        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
        if(a == 1){
            int m = scan.nextInt();

            if(bin[m] == 0){
                bin[m] = 1;
            }
            else if( bin[m] == 1){
                bin[m] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(a == 0){
            int l = scan.nextInt();
            int r = scan.nextInt();

            if(bin[r-1] == 0){
                System.out.println("EVEN");
            }
            else if(bin[r-1] == 1){
                System.out.println("ODD");
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: and where is the loop in this code you posted?

Comment: what's your scanner input?

Comment: so what is the value of a

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It was always there, just not formatted :-\

Comment: Because it doesn't run the loop, obviously. Even though it's lost in your source.

Comment: Are you sure your loop is executing ?

Comment: what's the value of `N2`

Answer (score 0):

I think that N2 is some constant (size or something) and as I can see from source code you are not calling **System.out.println(N2)** inside the loop (or even modify N2) so you can't expect to print it or even change it. Also even your question from topic is quite enigmatic cause how do you expect to see something in loop while printing it outside of loop?